# Custom jQuery slider with infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a custom slider for a site im working on only im struggling with the problem of how to make the slideshow loop, so when the slider loads, if you click left it will go the the last element if this makes sense?

```
$('.leftslide').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('.landingPageBanner .active').is(':first-child')) return;
    $('.landingPageBanner .active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
    var newH1 = $('.landingPageBanner ul li.active').data('heading');
    var newP = $('.landingPageBanner ul li.active').data('paragraph');
    var newA = $('.landingPageBanner ul li.active').data('link');
    $('.mask h1').html(newH1);
    $('.mask p').html(newP);
    $('.mask .view-sector').attr('href', newA);
});

$('.rightslide').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('.landingPageBanner .active').is(':last-child')) return;
    $('.landingPageBanner .active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    var newH1 = $('.landingPageBanner ul li.active').data('heading');
    var newP = $('.landingPageBanner ul li.active').data('paragraph');
    var newA = $('.landingPageBanner ul li.active').data('link');
    $('.mask h1').html(newH1);
    $('.mask p').html(newP);
    $('.mask .view-sector').attr('href', newA);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ss62/3/

Comment: Do you want the slider to go left or right until the end after an X time or what?

Comment: I want it to just keep scrolling @briosheje, If you click left when it first loads it doesnt do anything...

Comment: Well, then you may use a `setTimeout` that calls a function that slides until someone clicks left or right :P. Oh, reading the answers below I think I didn't get what you want to do :P

Comment: @briosheje Even if you were right, you should always pause a gallery on hover, not on button click. (From a UX perspective, the user might want to first read the current slide, before continuing to the next (eventually!))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on the first child of the slideshow, you want to activate the last child when you wrap around while clicking the 'left' link:

```
$('.leftslide').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('.landingPageBanner .active').is(':first-child')) {
        $('.landingPageBanner .active').removeClass('active').siblings(':last-child').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.landingPageBanner .active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
    }
```

Similarly, when clicking the 'right' link:

```
$('.rightslide').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('.landingPageBanner .active').is(':last-child')) {
        $('.landingPageBanner .active').removeClass('active').siblings(':first-child').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.landingPageBanner .active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/75fQx/

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is all you need:

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/fecep/6/edit)**

```
var $UL = $('.landingPageBanner ul'),   // Cache your selectors
    $LI = $('li', $UL),                 // 
    N   = $LI.length;                   // Count LI elements

$('.leftslide, .rightslide').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var R = $(this).hasClass('rightslide'),        // (Boolean) was Right clicked?
      I = $('.active', $UL).index(),             // Get idx of current LI
      D = $LI.removeClass('active').eq((R?++I:--I)%N).addClass('active').data();
      // (Above) Set active classes and get .data() Object from '.active' el.

  $('.mask h1').html(D.heading);        // think about Caching this selectors too
  $('.mask p').html(D.paragraph);
  $('.mask .view-sector').attr('href', D.link);

});
```

<sup>to explain this line:

 `$LI.removeClass('active').eq((R?++I:--I)%N).addClass('active').data();`</sup>

what it does is to target the `.eq( I )` LI element saying:

```
R   ? // was the right button clicked?
++I : // TRUE : increment our index
--I   // FALSE: decrement our index
// and make sure to return a reminder (%N) from the total LI el. length
// The Reminder Operator % will return 'I' index to '0' if equals or exceeds 'N'
```

now that the classes are removed/assigned all we need is to store into var `D` the current *active* LI's `.data()`.

Also remember that `.data()` returns an Object so make your life easier and use accordingly i.e: `D.heading`