# Convert a custom slider to infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Html:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="oCarol">
    <div class="button butLeft"> <a role="button" data-direction="left" href="#"><img alt="Goto previous slide" name="Previous" src="http://ch-harmeet.cloudapp.net/wp-content/themes/knowhow/images/left_arrow.png" /></a>

    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <ul class="panel-inner">
            <li class="sliderDarkBg panSlide1 clearfix">1</li>
            <li class="sliderDarkBg panSlide1 clearfix">2</li>
            <li class="sliderDarkBg panSlide1 clearfix">3</li>
            <li class="sliderDarkBg panSlide1 clearfix">4</li>
            <li class="sliderDarkBg panSlide1 clearfix">5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="button butRight"> <a role="button" data-direction="right" href="#"><img alt="Goto Next Slide" title="Next" src="http://ch-harmeet.cloudapp.net/wp-content/themes/knowhow/images/right_arrow.png" /></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Problem #1:** When I try to scroll right after 5th slide, it scrolls back to the first slide, is there anyway to make this an infinite loop?

**Problem #2:** Automatic scroll of the slider. I have created the following function to achieve this, is there a better way to do that?

```
function startSetInterval() {
    $('.button a:first-child').bind('trigger');
    timer = setInterval(function() { $('.button a:first-   
    child').trigger('click'); }, 5000);
}
```

[Fiddle Link.](http://jsfiddle.net/40g7d9mt/1/)

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370271/custom-jquery-slider-with-infinite-loop

Comment: Refer to this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15877302/5965558)